# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate an input field using the following pattern but i get this error :

```
<input id="testMyU" type="text" required maxlength=35 pattern="((?!((&[^\ ]*;))|([<>])).)*" >
```

Error :

```
Pattern attribute value ((?!((&[^\ ]*;))|([<>])).)* is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /((?!((&[^\ ]*;))|([<>])).)*/: Invalid escape
```

I don't find my mistake ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<input id="testMyU" type="text" required maxlength=35 pattern="((?!((&[^\ ]*;))|([<>])).)*" >
                                                                        ^
```

Try using a double backslash.

Comment: Good! Kindly click the tick icon to mark this as answered :)

Comment: you save my time.